# Ajax call interrupted by navigation

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I'm running into the following problem in my js code:

```
doStuff() {
    ...
    AnalyticsService.trackStuff(); // ajax call
    window.location.href = url;    // navigates to new page
}
```

`AnalyticsService.trackStuff()` gets interrupted when navigating to another page. Unfortunately it's in a library I can't modify (else I'd stick the navigation code in its callback).

Any advice on how to prevent `trackStuff()` from being interrupted?

Answer (score 0):

If  `AnalyticsService.trackStuff()` returns a promise you can do the following:

```
doStuff() {
    ...
    // ajax call
    AnalyticsService.trackStuff().then(function(result) {
        window.location.href = url; // navigates to new page
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Oh noes! It broke");
    });
}
```

You can find more about promises [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=en).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't :( Looks like it just uses pure ajax.